# Simple VBA function that returns product of range value

Tags: excel, product, vba

I want the function to take a range of cells as an argument and return their product. 
Let's assume the following value for cells:

```
A1=5 
A2=2 
A3=3
```

Let's call the function `Multiply`.
    `=Multiply(A1:A3)` will return 30 (=5×2×3).

What is the code for this? I'm just trying to familiarize myself with the syntax and this will help out a lot.

Edit: figured it out:

```
Function multiply(rng As Range)

    multiplied = 1

    For Each cell In rng
        multiplied = multiplied * cell.Value
    Next

    multiply = multiplied

End Function
```

Comment: It's great that you figured it out by yourself, but this loses to the built-in `=PRODUCT` formula or its VBA equivalent given below because of two things: One, it's a custom function so it's already naturally slower, and it's in a loop which compounds the slowness more. Second, you haven't accounted for ranges with no values in them. `PRODUCT` does. If you have to absolutely go with your function, at least add a `If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then...` condition. Otherwise, you risk getting a `0` when you have empty cells.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `VBA` version of `PRODUCT` directly, ie

```
MsgBox WorksheetFunction.Product([a1:a3])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use excel worksheet functions.

The default behaviour of `SUMPRODUCT` if there is only a single range provided is to return the sum so you can just pass the range to `SUMPRODUCT` this way:

```
WorksheetFunction.Sumproduct(**your range goes here**)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK for `=PRODUCT`, which does the job (`SUMPRODUCT` will NOT do what the initial fellow asked).

But, just for fun, using the properties of the math functions EXP and LN we have that if

```
X = A1*B1*C1 then 
LN(X) = LN(A1)+LN(B1)+LN(C1)
and
X = EXP(LN(X)) or
X = EXP(LN(A1)+LN(B1)+LN(C1))
```

so just put in a `cel: =EXP(SUM(LN(A1:C1)))` and voilà! (you must use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

Answer (score 0):

If you insist of writing your own function then try the following. It loads all the values into memory first and thus should work faster.

```
Public Function RngProduct(ByRef r as Range) as Double
    Dim vals() as Variant, res as Double
    vals = r.Value
    Dim i as Long, N as Long
    N = r.Rows.Count
    res = #1
    For i=1 to N
      res = res * vals(i,1)
    Next i
    RngProduct = res
End Function
```